# Symfony - Subquery in doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a set of posts on monthly basis. i need an array which contains total records of posts posted in each month (including zeros).
I fail to write it in dql :( Any ideas plz ?

Sample Data:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
| 24 | 2012-12-16 16:29:56 |
|  1 | 2013-02-25 14:57:09 |
|  2 | 2013-02-25 14:59:37 |
|  4 | 2013-02-25 15:12:44 |
|  5 | 2013-02-25 15:14:18 |
|  7 | 2013-02-26 11:31:31 |
|  8 | 2013-02-26 11:31:59 |
| 10 | 2013-02-26 11:34:47 |
| 14 | 2013-03-04 04:39:02 |
| 15 | 2013-03-04 05:44:44 |
| 16 | 2013-03-04 05:48:29 |
| 19 | 2013-03-07 15:22:34 |
| 20 | 2013-03-15 12:24:43 |
| 21 | 2013-03-16 16:27:43 |
| 22 | 2013-03-16 16:29:28 |
| 23 | 2013-03-16 16:29:56 |
| 11 | 2013-03-17 11:35:12 |
+----+---------------------+
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT count(b.id) as totalRec
FROM   (
            SELECT 'January' mnth
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'February' mnth
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'March' mnth
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN post b
            ON a.mnth = DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%M') AND
               year(b.date) =  '2013' AND 
               DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%M') IN ('January', 'February', 'March') 
GROUP  BY year(b.date)-month(b.date) 
ORDER  BY b.date ASC
```

OUTPUT

```
+----------+
| totalRec |
+----------+
|        0 |
|        7 |
|        9 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Count all posts grouped by month, and filter out the months you want:

```
SELECT count(*) as totalRec, DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%m%Y') as month
FROM post b
WHERE month IN('012013', '022013', '032013')
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY b.date ASC
```

Will result in:

```
+----------+----------+
| totalRec | month    |
+----------+----------+
|        0 |   012013 |
|        7 |   022013 |
|        9 |   032013 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: thx man, but if there is no records for '012013' the result wil 
+----------+----------+
| totalRec | month    |
+----------+----------+
|        7 |   022013 |
|        9 |   032013 |
+----------+----------+

Comment: you have no idea how can i do it ??